# Spectrum of sum of two commuting self-adjoint operators with different spectrum classification

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, generalized-eigenvector

I got curious while studying quantum mechanics. Suppose we have two self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ and let's say they do commute as well.
Let $\sigma(A)$ be a pure point spectrum of $A$ and $\sigma(B)$ be singular (or absolute) continuous spectrum of $B$.
Then what is a spectrum of $A + B$? Is it singular (or absolute) continuous? Or pure point spectrum? What do you think? It would be a great help if relevant references are provided, if you know any. Thanks : )

Comment: Regarding one aspect of your question: You are dealing with matrices with finitely many entries, right? Then there are only finitely many eigenvalues, hence the spectrum is discrete.

Comment: Aha. That's right. But what happens if one considers an infinite dimension??

Comment: In that case: How would you define a tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: By the way: Although it is not directly related to your question, you might be interested in following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_about_perturbation

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The tridiagonal matrices are just an example of self adjoint operators which commute each other. So one can think some general self-adjoint operators which commute. I will edit the question, since it can confuse people.